Regarding cursor pagination in REST API using `public_id`
I'm creating an API that returns public_id to the client while keeping the actual ID private, and I've created tables like below.
posts:
  id: bigint
  public_id: bigint # kind of snowflake unique id
  user_id: bigint

users:
  id: bigint
  public_id: random string # similar to NanoID

follows:
  id: bigint
  user_id: bigint
  target_user_id: bigint

In the posts list, I'm sorting by public_id on the server and returning public_id to the client, implementing cursor pagination.
On the other hand, in the users list, I'm sorting by ID and returning public_id to the client, but I'm unable to implement cursor pagination. How do I implement this case?
I considered using UUID ver7 or ULID for the users' public_id, but I don't want to use them because they reveal the date and result in long strings.
Additionally, how can I implement cursor pagination for followers/following lists based on intermediate tables like follows?
Returning encrypted IDs to the client would solve the issue, but I'm unsure if this is a common or recommended approach. Are there any better alternatives?
I have read the following some articles, but I don't know a good way to do it.

https://planetscale.com/blog/why-we-chose-nanoids-for-planetscales-api
https://medium.com/@conrardy/graphql-cursor-connections-cursor-specification-791c35c80424

